# How do I obtain values(lines) from file2 using only indices in file1?

Tags: python

I have one file1 with only indices, and second file2 contains the values of these indices of file1. How do I obtain these values from file2 using the indices in file1, and output its value to a third file.For simplicity sake, every index in file1 has its associated values in file2.

For example:

file1:

```
2
3
4
```

file2 contents:

```
0.24  0.43             
0.34  0.28              
7.50  0.67               
0.23  0.78               
0.45  0.49
```

Expected result

```
7.50 0.67
0.23 0.78
0.45 0.49
```

file1 #contains only indices
file2 #every index in file1 contains values with associated indices

```
fname = file1.readlines()
fname2 = file2.readlines()
outfile = open('Values.txt','w')

for index in fname:
  for line in fname2:
    if line == index:
      outfile.writelines(line)

print "all indices' values have been written to a file success
```

Comment: Are the indices in file1 monotonic?

Answer (score 1):

These solutions do not rely on file1 being ordered, however they do load file2 into memory, which could be costly if file2 is large. you will notice however that wanted_lines and lines_out are generators in the first example, which should save a small amount of memory.

This example has no error handling, but is basically what you need. I'll knock together a better one in a sec.

```
wanted_lines = (int(line) for line in open(file1).readlines())
all_lines = [line.strip() for line in open(file1).readlines()]
lines_out = (all_lines[index] for index in wanted_lines)
open(file3, 'w').writelines(lines_out)
```

---

Better:

```
all_lines = [line.strip() for line in open(file2).readlines()]
lines_out = []
for line in open(file1).readlines():
  try:
    index = int(line)
    lines_out.append(all_lines[index] + '\n')
  except IndexError:
    print file1, "is only", len(file1), "lines long, therefore has no", index+1, "th line."
  except:
    print "could not coerce", line.strip(), "to an int"
open(file3, 'w').writelines(lines_out)
```

Comment: `eval(line)` is incredibly evil when `int(line)` will do the job quite happily. What happens when file1 looks like `1\n2\nrm -rf *` (or equivalent)?

Comment: As I said - the first one was a basic version off the top of my head, just to get it down - you'll see that not only have I improved upon it, but I have given a better version, before you commented.

Comment: @BiggAl: I think your 'improvement' reads file1 twice and file2 not at all, is looking at the line numbers as strings, intends to pull file2 entirely into memory, does not close files (expects the instance-counter to take care of it instead of using `with`)...

Comment: @Hugh The reading of the same file twice was sloppy typing, however open(filename).readlines() does not leave the file open - it reads the lines from the file and closes it as if you were processing it within a `with`. And yes it loads the files into memory - looking at the sort of data it should be fairly cheap to do so, and seems clearer. Any other observations to add?

Comment: @BiggAl: try the following: `f = open('data.txt')` `content = f.readlines()` `f.closed` results in False. Conclusion: file.readlines() does *not* close the file. When the reference to the open file goes out of scope, the object's reference counter goes to 0 and it is closed and deleted at some convenient later time. `with` is preferred. For such a trivial usage it doesn't make much difference, but why teach bad habits? Also, if you are going to read a file into memory, would it not make more sense to read file1 instead - it's almost certain to be smaller than file2. ;-) That is all.

Comment: This works fine, but it was printing all required lines on ONE long line. Thanks

Comment: @user587646 whoops - I forgot that lines have to be `'\n'` terminated - fixing

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = file1.readlines()
fname = [ int(i) for i in fname]
f = open("file2")
for number,line in enumerate(f):
    if number in fname :
         print line.rstrip()
f.close()
```

Comment: In `int(i.strip())`, the `.strip()` is redundant because int() swallows whitespace: ie, `int('   1  \n')` == 1

Comment: Hi Kurumi, Your code produces the expected result. Thanks alot.

Comment: Hi Kurumi, I was trying your  sample solution for the given problem.I got this error Message: ValueError:invalid literal for int() with base10: ''. Can you look at it again. Thanks.

Comment: @user, does your input file have blanks? remove them if you have

Answer (score 0):

```
def copyLines(infname, outfname, lines, firstLine=0):
    lines = list(set(lines))   # remove duplicates
    lines.sort(reverse=True)   # sort in descending order
    with open(infname, 'r') as inf, open(outfname, 'w') as outf:
        try:
            i = firstLine
            while lines:
                seek = lines.pop()
                while i<seek:
                    inf.next()
                    i += 1
                outf.write(inf.next())
                i += 1
        except StopIteration:  # hit end of file
            pass

def main():
    with open('file1') as inf:
        linesToRead = [int(ln) for ln in inf]

    copyLines('file2', 'Values.txt', linesToRead)        

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Note that this will quit early if all desired lines have been found (ie if you only want lines 3-9 of a 1000-line file, it will only read to line 9).

Comment: This relies on the line numbers being ordered. What if file1 read '1\n2\n5\n4'?

Comment: @BiggAl: this is true and intentional as I am accessing the data file sequentially. If that usage case is ever desired then a different solution would be required.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to do that, you can use a oneliner bash

```
join file1 <(grep -v '^$' file2 | cat -n ) | cut -d ' ' -f 2- > Values.txt
```

but here, indices starts at 1 instead of 0. To start at 0:

```
join <(awk '{print $1+1}' < file1)  <(grep -v '^$' file2 | cat -n) | cut -d ' ' -f 2- > Values.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If file2's lines don't have to be written in the order they appear in file1, and if file1's contents are small enough to fit in RAM, this should do it efficiently:

```
outfile = open('Values.txt','w')
desired = set(int(line) for line in open('file1').readlines())
for index, line in enumerate(open('file2')):
    if index in desired:
        outfile.write(line)
```

This differs from kurumi's answer mainly in that it uses a set to hold the line numbers from file1 (O(1) instead of O(n) for checking whether to emit a line), and it uses file.write so no whitespace is altered from the original lines in file2.

Comment: I encountered this error message: ValueError:invalid literal for int() with base10: I  was substracting 1 from every indices, because the index is from Matlab as the matlab starts at 1 instead of 0. Can anyone of help me.

Comment: That sounds like you have a non-int value in file1. What value is it choking on? It might be that you have an extra newline at the end of it.

Comment: output of indices from matlab in file1. Error Message: ValueError:invalid literal for int() with base10: ''. I have tried all the solution samples given for this question. All came up with the same int  problem.

Comment: Run this: `for line in open('file1'): print line; print int(line)` and see what line it fails on. Since the problem is universal to every solution on this page, it means you have something other than a valid integer on at least one line in file1. This will help you find it.

Answer (score 0):

This version does not assume that indices in file1 are sorted.

```
indices = [int(x) for x in file("file1").readlines()]
data = file("file2").readlines()

for i in indices:
    print data[i]
```

Comment: This also gave the required values. Thanks Rumple.